# Find a probability distribution of $X$ such that $X+1$ has p.m.f. $p(i)$

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory

> Find a probability distribution of $X_1$ with $\mu=\mathbb{E}(X_1)>0 $ which taking values in $\mathbb{N}$ such that $X_1+1$ has p.m.f.(probability mass function) $p(i)$  where $$p(i)=\frac{i\mathbb{P}(X_{1}=i)}{\mu}, i\geq 1.$$

Comment: All you are given is that $\forall y\in\Bbb N^+:\mathsf P(X_1+1=y)=p(y)$.  You want to find the missing piece to $\forall x\in\Bbb N:\mathsf P(X_1=x)=\underline\qquad$.

Comment: It seems to me that the i.i.d. sequence has nothing to do with this problem. Nor do bounded convergence theorem concepts.

Comment: @Michael I have added the background of this question.

Comment: @GrahamKemp So what do you mean?

Comment: How to get a recursion of this one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An easier way to phrase it: find a nonnegative integer valued random variable $X$ such that $P(X+1=i)=\frac{i P(X=i)}{\mu}$ for all nonnegative integers $i$. To ease the notational burden a little bit, let $q_i=P(X=i)$, so the equation now reads $q_{i-1}=\frac{i q_i}{\mu}$. You can rewrite that as $q_i=\frac{\mu}{i} q_{i-1}$ for $i=1,2,\dots$.

Now the problem is just to find $q_0$ with the desired properties. (Such a $q_0$ may or may not be able to exist for arbitrary positive real numbers $\mu$, so you will need to be careful about that.)

Comment: Require $i\geq 1$, then I can get the $q_i=(\mu^{i-1}/i!) q_1$

Comment: The problem statement seems that does not give any information about the $q_1$ and $\mu$. Since the problem asks to find the $q_1$.

Comment: @LoveQYG You should check the notation of your reference, because I suspect that for them $\mathbb{N}$ includes $0$ (so that $q_0$ is a thing). This may make sense after you see how the problem ultimately turns out when you make that assumption...

Comment: But $\mathbb{P}(X=0)$ does not make sense which is there is not ball.

Comment: @LoveQYG How do you figure? There are different colors of balls, why shouldn't some color not be in the box at all?

Comment: Do I know the $\mathbb{P}(X=0)$? Is different from $\mathbb{P}(X=1)$

Comment: @LoveQYG You have $q_i=\frac{\mu}{i} q_{i-1}$. As a sanity check, multiply both sides by $i$ and sum over $i$ from 1 to infinity ($i=0$ doesn't contribute anything to the expectation). You should get $\mu=\mu$ which makes sense. To actually proceed, you can solve the recursion for $q_i$ as a function of $i,\mu$ and $q_0$, and then sum $q_i$ over $i$ from 0 to infinity. From this you will get a relation between $q_0$ and $\mu$.

Comment: Yes, I get the $q_0=e^{-\mu}$ and $q_i=e^{-\mu}\mu^i/i!$. So $q_i=Poisson(\mu)$. Is $\mu$ known? I am not sure.

Comment: @LoveQYG I think the question only really makes sense if $\mu$ is a given positive number.